# "mcrypt_module_open is deprecated" exception in cron in Magento 2.2.6 on PHP7.1 ?

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.2

The method is silenced in core still cron throws exception if debbug mode is enabled.

`mcrypt_module_open is deprecated`

```
  // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
  $this->_handle = @mcrypt_module_open($cipher, '', $mode, '');
  // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
```

What could be the reason?